# Underscore.js - Imperative & Functional exercise

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, imperative-programming

I'm learning about Underscore.js and the higher order functions. I came across the following problem, and I'm just simply stuck.

I'm not looking for a handout but at the same time, I don't have anywhere to turn for guidance in this. I would love someone to at least point me in the right direction.

What exactly does it mean by imperative vs functional?

I don't even know where to start when it comes to completing the 'functional' solution.

Any helpful info on this subject would be so much appreciated.

Please note: I do understand what map(), flatten(), and reduce() do. I just don't know how to apply it to this situation.

I do NOT understand what 'functional' really means. I would love any insight.

```
var products = [
    {
        name: 'Sonoma',
        ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'],
        containsNuts: false,
    },
    {
        name: 'Pizza Primavera',
        ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'],
        containsNuts: false,
    },
    {
        name: 'South Of The Border',
        ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'],
        containsNuts: false,
    },
    {
        name: 'Blue Moon',
        ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'],
        containsNuts: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'Taste Of Athens',
        ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'],
        containsNuts: true,
    },
];

// Underscore.js

// Count the ingredient occurence

// IMPERATIVE example:
var ingredientCount = { "{ingredient name}": 0 };

for (i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < products[i].ingredients.length; j += 1) {
        ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] =
            (ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] || 0) + 1;
    }
}

expect(ingredientCount['mushrooms')]).toBe(2);


// FUNCTIONAL: 
/* chain() together map(), flatten() and reduce() */

var ingredientCount = { "{ingredient name}": 0 };

// ? ? ?

expect(ingredientCount['mushrooms']).toBe(2);
```

Comment: You need to be able to walk before you can run. Having some basic familiarity with `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` (which are part of the standard JS array type, and aren't Underscore specific), will go a long way towards helping you think about how to solve this kind of problem using a functional approach.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Sorry my post was not clear. I actually do understand what `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` do. I just do not understand how it applies here, and what 'functional' actually means.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming. The relevance here is that you'd compose a function that carries out the equivalent of the imperative, loop based transformation shown, by instead using array combinators and pure functions.

Comment: As an example, the imperative solution to "multiply every element in the array by two", is `const newArray = []; for (let i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) { newArray.push(oldArray[i] * 2); }`. The functional solution is: `const newArray = oldArray.map(i => i * 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break it down into parts.  First of all, you only care about the ingredients, but `products` contains a lot of extra information, so use `map` to just extract the ingredients.

Now you have ingredients in an array of arrays, but you just want one big array with all the ingredients, so use `flatten` to give you that.

Now you want to count the ingredients.  You can think of this as a series of reductions, where you have an object with the previous counts, and for this current item, you want to increment the count.  This can be done with a `reduce` that starts with an empty object.  I'll leave the implementation of the `incrementCount` function as an exercise for the reader.

```
const ingredients = _.map(products, p => p.ingredients);
const flatIngredients = _.flatten(ingredients);
const counts = _.reduce(flatIngredients, incrementCount, {});
```

With functional code, think of your data as passing through a series of transformations, each one bringing you closer to your goal, rather than one big loop you try to cram all your mutations into.

Comment: This is a great explanation. This really helped me to understand it better. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this so well.

Answer (score -2):

Functional means that every function that is called has a return value and usually no side effects ("pure"). It is a programming style that is very suitable for data transformations.

- `map` takes an array and returns an array with each item transformed.
- `reduce` goes through the array, always providing the previously returned value and the next item in the array, calculating a new value. Can be used to calculate sums and such.
- `flatten` makes a list of lists into just a list.

```js
var products = [
    {
        name: 'Sonoma',
        ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'],
        containsNuts: false,
    },
    {
        name: 'Pizza Primavera',
        ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'],
        containsNuts: false,
    },
    {
        name: 'South Of The Border',
        ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'],
        containsNuts: false,
    },
    {
        name: 'Blue Moon',
        ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'],
        containsNuts: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'Taste Of Athens',
        ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'],
        containsNuts: true,
    },
];

const result = products.reduce((allIngredients, item) => allIngredients.concat(item.ingredients), [])
   .reduce((counts, ingredient) => { 
     counts[ingredient] ? counts[ingredient]++ : (counts[ingredient] = 1);
     return counts
   }, {})

console.log(result);
```